# How to call an unimplemented C function in golang when I try to build a static linked library(.a)?

Tags: go, cgo

I want to build a static linked library(.a) for both Android and iOS projects to use.

The static linked library is written in golang, will be linked with main project(iOS & Android). And, it will use two functions implemented in main project.

Here's the codes which I used in golang project.

```
/*
    extern int setAddressFromSupernode(const char *ip, const char *subnetMark);
    extern int writeDataToTunnel(char data[], int length);
*/
import "C"
```

Note that *setAddressFromSupernode* and *writeDataToTunnel* is implemented in main project.

But when I try to build, it shows following error message:

*Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_setAddressFromSupernode", referenced from:
__cgo_2d208380f2f8_Cfunc_setAddressFromSupernode in _x002.o
(maybe you meant: __cgo_2d208380f2f8_Cfunc_setAddressFromSupernode)
"_writeDataToTunnel", referenced from:
__cgo_2d208380f2f8_Cfunc_writeDataToTunnel in _x002.o
(maybe you meant: __cgo_2d208380f2f8_Cfunc_writeDataToTunnel)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)*

What I want is like this:

Main Project(JAVA or Objective-C) ---call---> Golang Project(static linked library .a) ----call---> Main Project functions

Is it possible? Or did I miss something?

Thank you all!

Comment: without knowing your code...did you build the static go lib with go >= 1.5 and  -buildmode=c-archive ?

Comment: Yes, I use go 1.17.3 and -buildmode=c-archive.

Comment: Here is the command I use to compile:
 CGO_ENABLED=1 \
 GOOS=ios \
 GOARCH=arm64 \
 SDK=iphoneos \
 CC=/usr/local/go/misc/ios/clangwrap.sh \
 CGO_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode" \
 go build -buildmode=c-archive -tags ios -o ./lib/ios/arm64.a ./cmd/

Comment: where are the functions implemented because in order to build a static lib you would usually need all the functions implemented somewhere?

Comment: The functions implemented in main project which I want build after the static lib. In fact, I've written the static lib in C and it worked well, but when I write it in Go, why should I implement all functions ?

Comment: sounds like a circular dependency? in order to build the static go lib you need an object file from the main project and in order to build the main project you need the static lib? you could link your go static lib to the functions from the c static lib you wrote, if i got it right?

Comment: I've asked my friends. They suggested me to write another lib by Objective-C to implement those functions. T_T I think it's very strange because when I chose C to write the sub project, it worked well though a circular dependency existed. Maybe xcode helped me to do some work and resolved the problem ?

Comment: can you create object files with clang for those functions...then you could use those for creating the go lib?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm going to do. Thank you !